# Rajawali library - Texture is not loading through .obj

Tags: android, opengl-es, rajawali

I am struggling to render texture using rajawali library. 
My Code is below,

```
ObjParser objParser = new ObjParser(mContext.getResources(), mTextureManager,    
                                    R.raw.objtest);
objParser.parse();
mObjectGroup = objParser.getParsedObject();
```

Same as specified in sample.

As specified in tutorial I have moved all images into nodpi folder. obj and mtl files are in raw folder.

I have exported obj from blender using right checked images. It is rendering texture properly in blender with "*Render Images Option*", but it is not able to render texture when i use option for "*open GL render image*"

Though with same approach Rajawali sample if loading texture properly.

Is this seems to be a problem with obj file or way I am rendering the obj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved issue, It was issue of images, we need to use power of 2 images.

Please find [link](https://github.com/MasDennis/Rajawali/issues/1064).

Comment: i need your help to serialise of ArrayList<BluetoothGattServices> and store to db. how ? any idea ?

Comment: This question is irrelevant to current post. Please ask in another post.:d